# Understanding the Euler sequence on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, exact-sequence

I want to get an intuition for the Euler sequence by understanding the explicit construction of maps between terms.
I prefer to use this version:
$$
0 
\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}
\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}
\longrightarrow T\mathbb{P}^n 
\longrightarrow 0
$$
rather than its dual or any twisted version.

**Conventions**:
$[x_0 : x_1 : \dots :x_n]$ are projective coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^n$. I will slightly abuse notation and describe sections of degree $d$ line bundles with the same notation, e.g. $x_0^d + 2x_1^{d-1}x_2$ is a section of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$.

**First map**

If $c$ is a locally constant function on $\mathbb{P}^n$, then
$$
f: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)},
\quad
c \mapsto (c\cdot x_0, c \cdot x_1, \dots,c\cdot x_n)
$$
i.e. multiplication of the linear monomials by $c$ (which is usually taken to be 1).

**Second map**

For a set of linear (homogeneous degree 1) functions $l_i(x)$, $i=0,\dots,n$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$, we have
$$
g: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}
\longrightarrow T\mathbb{P}^n ,
\\
(l_0(x), l_1(x), \dots, l_n(x))
\longmapsto
l_0(x) \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_0} + 
l_1(x) \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_1} + \dots +
l_n(x) \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_n}
$$

**Showing $\mathrm{im}(f) = \mathrm{ker}(g)$**

If we apply $(g\circ f)$ onto our locally constant $c$, we arrive at the vector
$$
c \cdot x_0 \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_0} + 
c \cdot x_1 \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_1} + \dots + 
c \cdot x_n \frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_n},
$$
which is known as the "Euler vector field" or EVF (or at least, it is $c$ times the usual definition of the EVF). It should be straightforward to see that the EVF acting on a homogeneous polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $d$ will return $d \cdot q(x)$. In particular, if $q$ is homogeneous of degree $0$, i.e. constant, then the EVF($q$) returns 0.

**This is where my understanding gets a little shaky:**

- The above makes sense, but the statement I see in the literature jumps from saying "the EVF annihilates degree 0 functions" to saying that "the EVF is the kernel of $g$" and concluding the description. This is a little hard for me to parse because I feel $\mathrm{ker}(g)$ lies in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus(n+1)}$, but the EVF seems to lie in $T\mathbb{P}^n$.
- Another point -- which may be central to the whole issue -- is if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are a proper set of basis vectors for $\mathbb{P}^n$. The $x_i$ are homogeneous coordinates after all, so is the resolution to my question that:
  $$
  x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 
  $$
  (note the $j$ index, $j=1,\dots,n$
  are a basis of $T\mathbb{P}^n$, but the EVF
  $$
  x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} 
  $$
  is actually the $\vec{\mathbf{0}}$ vector? Should we be working with affine coordinates on a patch, e.g. $y_i = x_i/x_0$ on the patch $x_0 \neq 0$?

I hope to have a picture that intuitively maps $c$ to the zero vector field in $T\mathbb{P}^n$, and the above steps don't quite get me there.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783633/tangent-bundle-of-pn-and-euler-exact-sequence/783850#783850) is explicitly an approach in which you said you were not interested, but it might give you some insight, anyhow. Yes, the Euler vector field on $\Bbb C^{n+1}$ descends to the $0$ vector tangent to $\Bbb P^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks - I did come across this earlier and think I follow but it's still a tad too slick for me. I guess you are also pointing out that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)^{\oplus (n+1)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus {0}$?

Comment: You are right that a lot of small details are usually missing. The EVF is a vector field on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. The sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ are seen as functionals on lines in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and your map $g$ actually gives a vector field on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. The map you are looking for is actually $d\pi\circ g$ which gives a vector field on $\mathbb{P}^n$ (because it is invariant on the lines). Everything is more or less explained in Griffiths and Harris page 409

Comment: @nonreligious simple question: What's the defintion for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(d)$?

Comment: @BVquantization $\mathcal{O}(d)=\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes d}$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)=\mathcal{O}(-1)^{*}$, where the last bundle ${\mathcal{O}(-1)}$ is known as "the tautological bundle"