# How to show that the Tangent Space $T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^n$ is isomorphic to $z^{\perp}$

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Consider the complex space $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with the usual hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$. We can construct the projective space $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ by the equivalence relationship $\phi \sim \psi \iff \phi=a\psi$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and taking the quotient:
$$
\mathbb{C}P^{n} = \mathbb{C}^{n+1}/\sim.
$$
I want to prove that the tangent space $T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ at a point $[z] \in \mathbb{C}P^n$ ($[z]$ denotes the equivalency class of $z$) is isomorphic to the space $z^{\perp}$. I've been trying to follow the steps described in the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366739/fubini-study-metric-induced-by-submersion) related question but I haven't had much success. My issue is that, given the canonical projection
$$
\pi:\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\backslash \{0\}\to \mathbb{C}P^n\\
z\mapsto[z],
$$
how does one compute the explicit expression for the pushforward $\pi_*$? Given that the pushforward is defined by
$$
\pi_*:T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\to T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^n,
$$
once i have the expression for $\pi_*$, how can I show that $T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^n \cong z^{\perp}$?

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question or if it doesn't make sense, I've only recently started to study projective spaces and geometry, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Of course you mean $a\ne 0$. Of course, any two $n$-dimensional complex vector spaces are isomorphic, so you're actually asking for more. In fact, the isomorphism you're wanting isn't really right. You want $T_{[z]}\Bbb CP^n \cong \text{Hom}(\text{Span}(z),\text{Span}(z)^\perp)$. At any rate, you can find various posts on this, but perhaps my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783633/tangent-bundle-of-pn-and-euler-exact-sequence/783850#783850). Note that $\mathscr L$ is the tautological line bundle whose fiber at $[z]$ is $\text{Span}(z)$.

Comment: The tangent space $T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ at a point $[z] \in \mathbb{C}P^n$ is trivially isomorphic to the space $z^{\perp}$ (simply because both vectors spaces have the same dimension). What you mean is to show that $\pi_*$  maps $z^{\perp}$ isomorphically onto $T_{[z]}\mathbb{C}P^{n}$. You should edit your question.